# Spring Boot AWS ElastiCache

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elasticache

I'm using Spring Boot Annotations to use AWS ElastiCache.
In my Application Configuration I have:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ElastiCacheAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableElastiCache({@CacheClusterConfig(name = "mycache", expiration = 23)})
```

In my service I have:

```
@Cacheable(value = "mycache", key = "#key")
```

I tried to add a property in application-dev.properties:

```
spring.cache.type=NONE
```

It all works alright, but when I try to debug locally, my app tries to connect to Amazon ElastiCache and it gives some connection errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client is not initialized
at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.checkState(MemcachedClient.java:1623) ~[elasticache-java-cluster-client-1.0.61.0.jar:na]
at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.enqueueOperation(MemcachedClient.java:1617) ~[elasticache-java-cluster-client-1.0.61.0.jar:na]
at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.asyncGet(MemcachedClient.java:1013) ~[elasticache-java-cluster-client-1.0.61.0.jar:na]
at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1235) ~[elasticache-java-cluster-client-1.0.61.0.jar:na]
at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1256) ~[elasticache-java-cluster-client-1.0.61.0.jar:na]
at org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.memcached.SimpleSpringMemcached.get(SimpleSpringMemcached.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar:1.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:68) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:466) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:432) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:336) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:302) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at com.example.ExpensiveService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e10c10a8.calculateExpensiveValue(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.CacheController.getLookupObjectByName(CacheController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:261) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

I want to know if it's possible to disable cache locally so I can run unit tests and debug all the app.

Comment: Are you able to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Add `@Profile("!local")` on your ElasticConfig and use local profile on classpath or IDE.